# All core MediaWiki upgrade script (round 2)

Tags: bash, database, linux, modules, automation

The following script upgrades an existing, all core (no add ons) MediaWiki install. I run it with `set -x` for debugging (I avoid `set -euo` because I often run this script line by line and/or block by block and in case of typos or problems this terminates the session, which I don't want to happen).

I have double tested the script and it is working fine (if your hosting provider requires you to add a directory such as `public_html` on top of `web_application_root/domain` than of course it should be added and the script should be updated accordingly).

By the way, I double create backups; before running this entire script I create filetree and DB backups from my hosting provider's tools as well and store them on my own computer device, just in case.

### Code

#### File 1: General preface

```
#!/bin/bash

## Declare latest mediawiki core download link:
latest_mediawiki_core="https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.35/mediawiki-1.35.1.tar.gz"

## Declare web application variables:
read domain
read db_name
read db_nonroot_user_name
web_application_root="${HOME}/www"
domain_dir="${web_application_root}/${domain}"
```

#### File 2: Backups preface

```
#!/bin/bash

## Declare existing installation backup variables:
current_date="$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)" &&
general_backups_dir="${HOME}/mediawiki_general_backups" &&
specific_backups_dir="${HOME}/mediawiki_specific_backups"

## If fresh backup directories don't exist, create them:
# due to the rm -rf command below I personally prefer to first do a pre-script backup of both the DB and filetree
rm -rf "${general_backups_dir}" &&
mkdir -p "${general_backups_dir}" &&
rm -rf "${specific_backups_dir}" &&
mkdir -p "${specific_backups_dir}"

## Test existence of empty directories
ll "${general_backups_dir}" &&
ll "${specific_backups_dir}"
```

#### File 3: Database backups

```
#!/bin/bash

## Create database general backup:
mysqldump -u"$db_nonroot_user_name" -p "$db_name" > "${general_backups_dir}/${db_nonroot_user_name}-${current_date}.sql"

## Test database general backup:
ll $general_backups_dir
```

#### File 4: Filetree backups

```
#!/bin/bash

## Create filetree general backups:
zip -r "${general_backups_dir}/${domain}-directory-backup-${current_date}.zip" "${domain_dir}"

## Create filetree specific backups (Some files have shell glob patterns outside quote marks):
cp "${domain_dir}/LocalSettings.php" "${specific_backups_dir}" &&
cp "${domain_dir}/robots.txt" "${specific_backups_dir}" &&
cp "${domain_dir}/${domain}.png" "${specific_backups_dir}" &&
cp "${domain_dir}"/.htaccess* "${specific_backups_dir}" &&
cp "${domain_dir}"/google*.html "${specific_backups_dir}"

## Test filetree general backups:
ll $general_backups_dir

## Test filetree specific backups:
ll $specific_backups_dir
```

#### File 5: Installation

```
#!/bin/bash

## Prepare to download, install and configure MediaWiki and specific backups: ##
cd "${web_application_root}"
rm -rf "${domain_dir}"

## Download and configure MediaWiki core:
wget "${latest_mediawiki_core}" &&
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'mediawiki*.tar.gz' -type f -exec tar -xzf {} \; && 
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '*mediawiki*' -execdir mv {} "${domain}" \; &&
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'mediawiki*.tar.gz' -type f -exec rm {} \;

## Test previous operation: ##
ll

## Retrieve specific backups to the new installation:
cp -a "${specific_backups_dir}"/.htaccess "${domain_dir}" # Only .htaccess file;
cp -a "${specific_backups_dir}"/* "${domain_dir}" # All files besides .htaccess;

## Test specific backups retrieving:
ll ${domain_dir}
```

#### File 6: Configurations

```
## Prepare to create and configure a new sitemap and to update database:
cd "${domain_dir}"

## Create a new sitemap:
rm -rf "${domain_dir}/sitemap"
mkdir -p "${domain_dir}/sitemap"

php "${domain_dir}/maintenance/generateSitemap.php" \
--memory-limit=50M \
--fspath=/"${domain_dir}/sitemap" \
--identifier="${domain}" \
--urlpath=/sitemap/ \
--server=https://"${domain}" \
--compress=yes

# Ensure that robots.txt sitemap directive is:
# Sitemap: https://"${domain}"/sitemap/sitemap-index-"${domain}".xml

## Update database (One might need to change LocalSettings.php before doing so):
php "${domain_dir}/maintenance/update.php" --quick &&
php maintenance/rebuildrecentchanges.php
```

Comment: This question was [linked to at the MediaWiki support desk](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:W3sx24rgg0eul8zt)

Comment: Yes, and BTW, is there someone here whom will agree to add a "MediaWiki" tag in the tags section? Some MediaWiki engineers are registered users in the wide community and might get an RSS feed about this thread so (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks

File 1: General preface

```
## Declare web application variables:
read domain
read db_name
read db_nonroot_user_name
```

When the user is prompted for a string, please tell what is wanted:

```
read -p "Domain: " domain
read -p "Database name: " db_name
read -p "Datebase user (not admin): " db_nonroot_user_name
```

File 2: Backups preface

```
## Declare existing installation backup variables:
current_date="$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)" &&
general_backups_dir="${HOME}/mediawiki_general_backups" &&
specific_backups_dir="${HOME}/mediawiki_specific_backups"
```

Remove the `&&`, the assignment will work.

```
rm -rf "${general_backups_dir}" &&
mkdir -p "${general_backups_dir}" &&
rm -rf "${specific_backups_dir}" &&
mkdir -p "${specific_backups_dir}"
```

You do not have a check on the last command. When another command fails, the next command is skipped, but the script continues. Consider error handling like

```
die() {
   echo "Fatal error: $*"
   exit 1
}

rm -rf "${general_backups_dir}" || die "Removing ${general_backups_dir} failed."
mkdir -p "${general_backups_dir}" || die "Creating ${general_backups_dir} failed."
rm -rf "${specific_backups_dir}" || die "Removing ${specific_backups_dir} failed."
mkdir -p "${specific_backups_dir}" || die "Creating ${specific_backups_dir} failed.
```

"

```
## Test existence of empty directories
ll "${general_backups_dir}" &&
ll "${specific_backups_dir}"
```

Test is not needed with the `die` construction. When you want to test, use

```
test -d "${general_backups_dir}" || die "Missing ${general_backups_dir}."
```

File 4: Filetree backups

```
## Create filetree specific backups 
cp "${domain_dir}/LocalSettings.php" "${specific_backups_dir}" && ...
```

Test the copy result with

```
cp "${domain_dir}/LocalSettings.php" "${specific_backups_dir}" || die "cp LocalSettings failed."
```

File 5: Installation

```
## Prepare to download, install and configure MediaWiki and specific backups: ##
cd "${web_application_root}"
```

The cd commands are really important. What will happen, when the user doesn't has a www directory?

```
cd "${web_application_root}" || die "cd ${web_application_root} failed"
```

Remove with care

```
rm -rf "${domain_dir}"
```

Sure about this? Perhaps the user hit enter by accident when he was asked for a domain.